# Writing a dynamic where clause in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Hi i have a stored procedure which will have a dynamic clause, this is what my stored procedure looks like;

```
SELECT  Comment.AddDate,Event.StartTime,Users.Name
FROM Comment
JOIN Users on Users.USERS_ID  = Comment.UserID
JOIN Event ON Users.USERS_ID = Event.UserID
```

If i pass a variable @Name the stored procedure should then look like this;

```
SELECT  Comment.AddDate,Event.StartTime,Users.Name
FROM Comment
JOIN Users on Users.USERS_ID  = Comment.UserID
JOIN Event ON Users.USERS_ID = Event.UserID
WHERE Name = @Name
```

However there are cases whereby the @Name i pass in will be empty, which means i want everything returned and not based on a specific name.

Also in some cases i will also pass in an eventid, how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `COALESCE` function in your where clause to use either the variable or the existing value, something like:

`WHERE Name = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Name, ''), Name)
   AND EventID = COALESCE(@EventID, EventID)`

**UPDATE:**

I added the `NULLIF` function within the `COALESCE` which says that if the value of @Name is an empty string, treat it as NULL therefore allowing the `COALESCE` function to work properly.

Comment: Tried this, it didnt work, the problem is sometimes a @Name will be null which means everything should be returned.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. COALESCE essentially says if @Name is NULL, use the current Name value which results in Name = Name which should always be true.

Comment: You can try the `IS NULL OR` option as suggested by other users; I just prefer COALESCE

Comment: Tried it again, it does not work, maybe i am not explaining myself well. There are cases whereby the @Name i pass in will be empty, which means i want everything returned and not based on a specific name, in this case coalesce is not working.

Comment: @pmillio this should work for you, can you post your query where it does not work?

Comment: @pmillio if I understand you, you want to call my_sp(@Name, @EventID) where either @Name or @EventID could be null and you want to query to ignore the null parameter(s); that is exactly what `COALESCE` or `IS NULL OR` can be used for; it would definitely help to see your whole query as maybe there is something else causing unexpected results

Comment: I just reread your last comment and noticed the word "empty" are you saying that sometimes @Name = '' as opposed to NULL?

Comment: Yes sometimes an empty string is passed in to it. Maybe i am doing it the wrong way. However what i am trying to do is get comments, and in some cases get comments made by a specific user. If the @Name is empty then all comments are returned. I hope that makes sense

Comment: By the way this is my query SELECT  Comment.AddDate,Event.StartTime,Users.Name
FROM Comment
JOIN Users on Users.USERS_ID  = Comment.UserID
JOIN Event ON Users.USERS_ID = Event.UserID
WHERE Name = COALESCE(@Name, Name)

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, I will update my answer to account for empty string values.

Comment: Great work, it works fine. Thanks alot, i appreciate you taking the time to help me the whole way.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name = @Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

no need for dynamic sql, just try:

```
SELECT  Comment.AddDate,Event.StartTime,Users.Name
FROM Comment
JOIN Users on Users.USERS_ID  = Comment.UserID
JOIN Event ON Users.USERS_ID = Event.UserID
WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name = @Name)
OR (@Id IS NULL OR Id=@Id)
```

The `@var IS NULL` should short circuit the `column = @var` predicate if it is not supplied, this means you can supply either parameter to select your rows